# JPA reading XMLTYPE results in NullPointer

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Hi I already submitted this as a bug on the eclipselink website but there is no response so far and I'm stuck. I hope someone knows a workaround or something.
I got a single entity with no relations to other tables. The entity is mapping an existing table in an oracle database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIVERX_MUSTER16_PRUEFUNG")
@Customizer(XMLTypeAttributeCustomizer.class)
public class MYDATATABLE {

    ...
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "XML", columnDefinition = "XMLTYPE")
    private String xmlDocument;

    ...
}
```

I tried a lot of things but every time I try to do a select on this table eclipselink is throwing a NullPointerException

```
ERROR - EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getOracleObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:302)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:164)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java:121)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getObject(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.getObjectFromResultSet(Oracle9Platform.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.getObject(DatabaseAccessor.java:1302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.fetchRow(DatabaseAccessor.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processResultSet(DatabaseAccessor.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
```

If I remove the xmltype column everything works as expected. If I add the column again -> NullPointer...

Here is my XmlMapper so you can see that I did exactly as the tutorials to DirectXmlTypeMapping tell

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.xdb.DirectToXMLTypeMapping;


public class XMLTypeAttributeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize (ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
    // Remove JPA default Basic mapping
    descriptor.removeMappingForAttributeName("xmlDocument");
    final DirectToXMLTypeMapping mapping = new DirectToXMLTypeMapping();
    mapping.setAttributeName("xmlDocument");
    mapping.setFieldName("XML");
    mapping.getField().setColumnDefinition("XMLTYPE");
    descriptor.addMapping(mapping);
}
```

}

is there any workaround? I have to work with this table and it is not the only one that contains a XMLTYPE column... I am absolutely out of ideas here...

Comment: There are various discussions regarding this issue in various situations. One suggested solution seems to be to roll back  to an older version of the Oracle JDBC driver. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#es_th=1&q=at+oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.getOracleObject(NamedTypeAccessor.java%3A302)

Comment: You mention when you remove the xmltype column everything works, are you referring to the lob and column annotations, or everything such as the customizer as well?  How have you specified it so that the customizer gets called?

Comment: I meant if I remove the field. The variable itself with all annotation. The customizer is also definetely called. sysouts have proven that.
And I did not try to leave the customizer on the class when I removed the xml field

Answer (score 0):

problem was a bug in the oracle jdbc driver. The problem has been fixed in version 11.2.0.4